# Shopify Flow: Adding A Customer Tag IF They Purchase $25 Or More Products With Their Own Product Tag?

Tags: shopify

I tried asking in the Shopify forum, but the staff there only tells me what's wrong with my code and not how to fix it.

This was my most recent attemps

```
{% for line_item in order.lineItems %}

{% if order.lineItems.product.tags contains 'Type: Chewy Candy' %}

{% increment line_item.final_line_price %}

{% if line_item.final_line_price > 25 %}

MORE_THAN_25_TEST

{% else %}

LESS_THAN_25

{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

> A staff member there responded with this, but I don't know how to fix what I have based on this feedback.{ % if order.lineItems.product.tags contains 'Type: Chewy Candy' %}

You cannot access array items this way in Flow. You need to loop over each array.

{% increment line_item.final_line_price %}

line_items isn't a variable and generally Flow doesn't use underscore for the available variables. Use "Add a variable" to see the right way.

{% if line_item.final_line_price > 25 %}

final_line_price is not a field

I have tried continuously changing the liquid code and having it send me an email every time someone places an order, but I still can't get the data out of it that I'm going for.

Comment: Not clear, but actully you want to do